# regex match a word after a certain character

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match a word when it is after a char `m` or `b`

So for example, when the word is `men`, I would like to return `en` (only the word that is following `m`), if the word is `beetles` then return `eetles`

Initially I tried `(m|b)\w+` but it matches the entire `men` not `en`

How do I write regex expression in this case?
Thank you!

Comment: `re.findall(r'\b[mb](\w+)', text)`

Comment: `(?<=\b[mb])\w+` or `(?<=\b[mb])\w+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/ULFazR/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the match only using a positive lookbehind asserting what is on the left is either m or b using character class `[mb]` preceded by a word boundary `\b`

```
(?<=\b[mb])\w+
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is
- `\b[mb]` Word boundary, match either `m` or `b`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\w+` Match 1 + word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/baETvv/1)

If there can not be anything after the the word characters, you can assert a whitespace boundary at the right using `(?!\S)`

```
(?<=\b[mb])\w+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lPO1kQ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fUlR6y)

Example code

```
import re

test_str = ("beetles men")
regex = r"(?<=\b[mb])\w+"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['eetles', 'en']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
\b[mb](\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJFjM5/1).

**NOTE**: When your known prefixes include *multicharacter sequences*, say, you want to find words starting with `m` or `be`, you will have to use a non-capturing group rather than a character class: `\b(?:m|be)(\w+)`. The current solution can thus be written as `\b(?:m|b)(\w+)` (however, a character class here looks more natural, unless you have to build the regex dynamically).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[mb]` - `m` or `b`
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more word chars, letters, digits or underscores. To match only letters, use `([^\W\d_]+)` instead.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/bIAFAa):

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'\b[mb](\w+)')
text = "The words are men and beetles."
# First occurrence:
m = rx.search(text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))     # => en
# All occurrences
print( rx.findall(text) ) # => ['en', 'eetles']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[mb])\w+/
```

You can use this above regex. The regex means "Any word starts with m or b".

1. `(?<=[mb])`: [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
2. `\w+`: matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9]+)

Comment: This matching `out` in `about`